# selecting Label text which is before textbox

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-tools, validationsummary

i am using JQUery Tools - [Validation Error Summary](http://jquerytools.org/demos/validator/custom-effect.html)

```
/* adds an effect called "wall" to the validator */
        $.tools.validator.addEffect("wall", function(errors, event) {
                // get the message wall
                var wall = $(this.getConf().container).fadeIn();
                // remove all existing messages
                wall.find("p").remove();
                // add new ones
                $.each(errors, function(index, error) {
                    wall.append(
                        "<p><strong>" +error.input.attr("name")+ "</strong> " +error.messages[0]+ "</p>"
                    );
                });
                // the effect does nothing when all inputs are valid
        }, function(inputs)  {

        });
```

[image]

if u can see the image everything is working fine, what i want is, with changing this code,  instead of text-box name i want the Label text to be displayed before the Error MSG.

Thanks in Advance.
**EDIT** :HTML

```
<tbody style="" class="user_panel" id="customer_info">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><label class="label">Contact name:</label>
      <input type="text" value="" name="contact_name" class="" style="width:227px"></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><label class="label">Measurement:</label>
      <select value="" data-message="Measurement is required1" required="required" name="measurement" style="width: 231px; border-color: red;">
        <option value="">-select-</option>
        <option value="1">mm</option>
        <option value="2">inches</option>
      </select></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><label class="label">Phone personal:</label>
      <input type="text" value="" data-message="Pers cont. num is required" required="required" name="contact_number_person" class="" style="width: 227px; border-color: red;"></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
```

Comment: Can you post your html please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the your JavaScript under the **// add new ones** comment to this:

```
$.each(errors, function(index, error) {
    wall.append(
        "<p><strong>" +error.input.prev().html()+ "</strong> " +error.messages[0]+ "</p>"
    );
});
```

Instead of printing the name attribute of the input object, it will print the html inside the **previous** element which is the `label`

Answer (score 1):

If you add the attribute `for` to your labels, e.g.

```
<label class="label" for="contact_name">Contact name:</label>
```

Then you can have:

```
wall.append(
                    "<p><strong>" +$("label[for='"+ error.input.attr("name")+"']").text()+ "</strong> " +error.messages[0]+ "</p>"
                );
```

This addresses the possibility that another element is between the label and the input. Or if you want a label to follow an input.